# Is it normal that there are no questions asked during UK visit visa interview & biometric at VAC Malaysia?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I attended an interview to submit my documents & biometrics at the Visa Application Center (VAC) in Malaysia to visit the UK. I was prepared to all kind of questions with my wife who plans to accompany me.

However, to my surprise, the officer asked no questions at all.
They just introduced their fast services & countersigned our submitted documents.

Is that a normal procedure? Does this give a positive indication or has no relationship with visa approval status?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The UK does not generally conduct interviews for [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) applications (though there are routine interviews for [Tier 4 student visas](https://warwick.ac.uk/study/international/immigration/tier4/applying/credibility/)). Applicants are occasionally, rarely, [called for interviews](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/india/frequently_asked_questions.html) if the Consulate decides they want to talk to you, but most decisions are made by reviewing the application and supporting documents.

The person you saw works for the VAC and is there to collect your paperwork and biometrics. He or she is not a decision-maker (an Entry Clearance Officer, or ECO) and does not conduct any interviews. The VAC will package up your application and courier it off to UK Consular staff, who will review it and make a decision.

This is the normal procedure, and it means nothing as to whether your visa will be approved. At this point, your application is submitted, and there's nothing to be done but to wait for a decision, stressful as that can be.